# How to use the vision.GeometricShearer command so that it performs for up and down shearing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

```
h = vision.GeometricShearer('values' , [0 20]);
```

The above MATLAB command defines an object for horizontal shearing of an image.  Is there a way to define the same object but for up and down shearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, you have a small typo in your syntax.  `values` should be capitalized and so it's `Values`.  This apparently is case-sensitive.... which is a bit ridiculous, but that's the way it is.

---

Back to your post, you need to specify an additional flag to [`vision.GeometricShearer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.geometricshearer-class.html) that determines the direction of where you want to apply the shear.  Specifically, you need to set the `Direction` flag, and you set this to either `Horizontal` or `Vertical`.  If you omit this, the default is `Horizontal`.  As such, if you want to shear the last column of your image and move it down by 20 pixels, you would do this:

```
h = vision.GeometricShearer('Values', [0 20], 'Direction', 'Vertical');
```

If you want to visualize the results, you would use `step` and apply it to the image.  As an example, let's load in the `checkerboard` image that's part of the MATLAB system path, apply the shear, then show both of the results in the same figure:

```
%// Define vertical shear
h = vision.GeometricShearer('Values', [0 20], 'Direction', 'Vertical');
img = im2single(checkerboard); %// Read in image
outimg = step(h,img); %// Apply shear

%// Show both results
subplot(2,1,1), imshow(img);
title('Original image');
subplot(2,1,2), imshow(outimg);
title('Output image');
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: if i am taking image from camera , using this command can i make farthest pixel of image closer and closer to farthest ?

Comment: @AmitWaghmare - Thanks for accepting my answer!  As for your question, you would need a depth map for that or some measure of distance from each point that is imaged to the camera.  Even so, with this command, shearing is only limited to horizontal and vertical shearing and not any shearing that is perpendicular to the camera axis.  As such, no it isn't possible... at least not to my knowledge.